# axios.interceptors do not fire when fetching with php proxy

Tags: javascript, php, reactjs, proxy, axios

I am writing a react app that will consume services on a remote server.
When developing locally, using `react-scripts` server on `localhost:3000`, I use a browser with CORS disabled, and axios fetching works just fine: in case of error 400 from a service, for example, my interceptor fires and I can catch the error:

```
axios.interceptors.response.use(
  response => {
    return response;
  },
  err => {
    console.error(err); // error handling
  }
);
```

When running in production, I use a custom php proxy, prepending `"proxy.php?url="` to the remote url I use for fetching.
The proxy essentially does:

```
<?php
  ...
  $ch = curl_init($url);
  $result = curl_exec($ch);
  curl_close($ch);
  echo $result;
?>
```

When remote service returns successfully, everything works fine.
When remote service fails, for example with a 400 HTTP status code, the axios interceptor does not fire, so I can't react to the error condition in my js code.

Do you see any mistake in my assumptions?
Or any issue in the php proxy?
Or some flaw in my axios interceptor setup?
If I should give more code details I'll do it, of course.

Answer (score 0):

After a lot of fighitng against this issue, I finally found the solution, which was very simple...
My proxy simply did non output the headers coming from server response...
I simply changed

```
<?php
  ...
  $ch = curl_init($url);
  $result = curl_exec($ch);
  curl_close($ch);
  echo $result;
?>
```

to

```
<?php
  ...
  $ch = curl_init($url);
  $result = curl_exec($ch);
  curl_close($ch);
  $result = curl_exec($ch);
  list($result_headers, $result_body) = explode("\r\n\r\n", $result, 2);
  $headers = explode("\n", $result_headers);
  foreach ($headers as $h) {
    header($h);
  }
  echo $result_body;
?>
```